# Why does getInterpreter().adaptivePredict in generated parser return incorrect value?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr4, intellij-plugin

I am creating custom language (EO language) plugin for IntelliJ. I use antlr4 adapter and I've already generated parser and lexer. I am working on syntax highlighting.

ANTLR4 plugin allows building tokens tree for EO code. I used this option and pasted simple EO program, the tree was built successfully. Nevertheless when I paste this code in IDEA I see an error.
After doing a research I found that problem appears in `getInterpreter().adaptivePredict()`

In my grammar there are 2 possible code variants (case 1 and case 2 in code below) but `getInterpreter().adaptivePredict()` returns 3.

Why it works like this?
May be my grammar is not correct but it works in ANTLR tree viewer (I checked several times and added picture in this post)

EO program

```py
+alias org.eolang.io.stdout
+alias org.eolang.txt.sprintf


[args...] > main   # This line is an abstraction. Highlighting error (">" is red, expecting '' or EOL)
  [y] > leap
    or. > @
      and.
        eq. (mod. y 4) 0
        not. (eq. (mod. y 100) 0)
      eq. (mod. y 400) 0
  stdout > @
    sprintf
      "%d is %sa leap year!"
      (args.get 0).as-int > year!
      if. (leap year:y) "" "not "
```

It is how tree draws "abstraction" line in IDEA. It is correct.
[image]

Here is the code from my parser class.

```java
public final AbstractionContext abstraction() throws RecognitionException {
        AbstractionContext _localctx = new AbstractionContext(_ctx, getState());
        enterRule(_localctx, 10, RULE_abstraction);
        int _la;
        try {
            enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
            {
            setState(99);
            attributes();
            setState(107);
            _errHandler.sync(this);
    /* ? */ System.out.println(getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,14,_ctx));  // prints 3
            switch ( getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,14,_ctx) ) {
            case 1:
                {
                {
                setState(100);
                suffix();
                setState(104);
                _errHandler.sync(this);
                switch ( getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,13,_ctx) ) {
                case 1:
                    {
                    setState(101);
                    match(SPACE);
                    setState(102);
                    match(SLASH);
                    setState(103);
                    _la = _input.LA(1);
                    if ( !(_la==QUESTION || _la==NAME) ) {
                    _errHandler.recoverInline(this);
                    }
                    else {
                        if ( _input.LA(1)==Token.EOF ) matchedEOF = true;
                        _errHandler.reportMatch(this);
                        consume();
                    }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                setState(106);
                htail();
                }
                break;
            }
            }
        }
        catch (RecognitionException re) {
            _localctx.exception = re;
            _errHandler.reportError(this, re);
            _errHandler.recover(this, re);
        }
        finally {
            exitRule();
        }
        return _localctx;
    }
```

Here is part from EO.g4

```
abstraction
  :
  attributes
  (
    (suffix (SPACE SLASH (NAME | QUESTION))?)
    | htail
  )?
  ;
```

github link of project: https://github.com/yasamprom/EOplugin_antlrbased/blob/main/src/main/java/org/antlr/jetbrains/eo/parser/EOParser.java

Comment: There are a lot of issues here. The parse tree you show, gathered from Intellij with the Antlr plugin, is not what is produced by a generate parser in the plugin you are developing! The error recovery from the generated parser is completely different from the one in the Intellij Antlr plugin. Start with a simple java driver program with the generated parser and fix your [grammar](https://github.com/yasamprom/EOplugin_antlrbased/blob/main/src/main/antlr/org/antlr/jetbrains/eo/parser/EO.g4), which has newline and space problems, failing on line 4 of the input with an extra EOL.

Comment: What is the difference between tree generated by antlr plugin and PSI tree generated by parser? I thought parser should generate same tree

Comment: The Intellij Antlr plugin calls an ["interpreter"](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4#limitations). The plugin does not need to "generate" a parser first in order to you to view the tree for your input. In comparison, the tree for the input from a generated parser can be viewed [here](https://github.com/kaby76/so72231962/blob/main/test.out). The trees are not the same.

Comment: The problem was in handling spaces. Spaces have been ignored by parser. My ParserDefinition class was copied from jetbrains tutorial and there was a part with tokens ignored by parser. I removed `public TokenSet getWhitespaceTokens() {
 return WHITESPACE;
}` from this class and now my grammar works fine. Thanks to @kaby76 for clues